# Como ubico un objeto en posición de una matriz? SDL2

Tags: c++, game

estoy haciendo un juego y tengo que poner varias cosas en el mapa, ahora mismo estoy siguiendo un tutorial en ingles que define el mapa como una matriz, todo bien, la cosa es que pone el personaje en posicion de pantalla, no en posicion de la matriz,  y no se como hacer para poner mi personaje sobre la matriz.

CPP de mi personaje

```
locomotora::locomotora(const char* texturesheet, int x, int y){
objTexture = TextureManager::LoadTexture(texturesheet);
xpos = x;
ypos = y; }

void locomotora::Update(){
srcRect.h = 32;
srcRect.w = 32;
srcRect.x = 0;
srcRect.y = 0;

destRect.x = xpos;
destRect.y = ypos;
destRect.w = srcRect.w;
destRect.h = srcRect.h;  }

void locomotora::Render(){
SDL_RenderCopy(Game::renderer,objTexture, &srcRect, &destRect);  }
```

Y en el bucle del juego lo defino y lo llamo asi:

```
jugador = new locomotora("player.png", 700 ,600);
```

Cargo su png y los 2 números son los de posición en pantalla, que es de 800x600, ahora lo que yo quiero es ponerlo en la posición de la matriz que es de [25][20].
Alguien podría darme una mano? No encuentro casi nada relacionado con SDL2 en internet.
Y el objetivo del juego es que se mueva y vaya agregando vagones onda la viborita, esta bien implementar todo en base a una matriz como mapa para lograr eso? Gracias.